# What does Any.match do?

Tags: match, raku, seq, stringification

It has the deceivingly simple code:

```
 method match(Any:U: |) { self.Str; nqp::getlexcaller('$/') = Nil }
```

However, this is the behavior it has:

```
(^3).match(1) # OUTPUT: «｢1｣␤»
```

So far, so good.

```
say (1,3 ... * ).match(77); # OUTPUT: «Nil␤»
```

Ooookey. What's happenning now?

```
say (1,3 ... * ).match(1);    # OUTPUT: «Nil␤»
say (1,3 ... * ).match(/\d/); # OUTPUT: «Nil␤»
```

Does not like sequences.

```
say (^10).match(/\d/); # OUTPUT: «｢0｣␤»
```

OK, makes sense again.

```
say <a b c>.match(/\w/); # OUTPUT: «｢a｣␤»
```

Back to normal. So is it that it does not like Seqs? I assume, because I've looked at the other classes' code and `match` is not reimplemented, all of them are calling that code. But I fail to see how returning a string and setting a variable from NPQ does that, or why it does not work on sequences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.match` is a search for a needle in a single haystack string. An infinite sequence stringifies to `'...'`.

```
say (1,3 ... 9).Str;        # 1 3 5 7 9
say (1,3 ... 9).match: '1'; # ｢1｣

say (1,3 ... *).Str;        # ...
say (1,3 ... *).match: '.'; # ｢.｣
```

## How I worked this out

First, you're looking at the wrong method definition:

```
method match(Any:U: |) { ... }
```

`Any:U` is kinda like `Any $ where not .defined` except if it matched you would get the error message "Parameter '<anon>' of routine 'match' must be a type object of type 'Any', not an object instance ...".

But you're passing a *defined* `Seq`. So your `.match` calls don't dispatch to the method definition you're looking at.

To find out what a method dispatches to, use:

```
say (1,3 ... *).^lookup('match').package ; # (Cool)
```

A *defined* `Seq` will thus dispatch to [the `Cool` code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Cool.pm6#L161):

```
method match(Cool:D: |c) {
    ...
    self.Stringy.match(|c)
}
```

So, next:

```
say (1,3 ... *).^lookup('Stringy').package ; # (Mu)
```

And [the code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Mu.pm6#L568):

```
multi method Stringy(Mu:D $:) { self.Str }
```

So check:

```
say (1,3 ... *).Str; # ...
```

Bingo.

And confirm:

```
say (1,3 ... *).match: '.'; # ｢.｣
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer explains perfectly what's going on. I'm just adding this to show some examples of how to do what the OP seems to have intended.

```
doug$ perl6
To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> say (^3).any.match(/\d/)
any(｢0｣, ｢1｣, ｢2｣)
> say (^3).any.match(/\d/).so
True
> say (^3).any.match(/ <alpha> /).so
False
> say ('a'..'c').any.match(/ <alpha> /).so
True
> # say (0 ... *).any.match(/ \d /).so ## ==> never terminates
Nil
> say (0 ... *).first(/ \d /)
0
> say (0 ... *).first(/ \d\d /)
10
>
```